# how to write events in onclick of a hyperlink in ColModel of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to write events in onclick function of a hyperlink in ColModel of jqgrid.
how to call the function in onclick of a hyperlink column in jqgrid

js code is like this

```
colModel:[      
    {name:'controlCenterCode',
    formatter:'showlink',   //formatoptions:editControlCenterPage(results), formatoptions:onClick=editControlCenterPage(results),
    index:results.controlCenterCode, width:70}
```

directly calling the function is working, but I want to call the function in onclick of the cell in the particular columnn, how to solve it?

and I tried like this also, to directly include the hyperlink in the column, the also it is not working

```
{name:'controlCenterCode',index:"<span><a href='#'onclick='editControlCenterPage(results)'>"+results.controlCenterCode+"</a></span>", width:70}
```

Please suggest me a solution 
Thanks

Comment: There is usually a better solution than using an onclick attribute, such as delegating an event to anchor tags within the table that have a particular class.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the showlink formatter, but this should work for you:

Add a [live event handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to your links:

```
$('[aria-describedby="gridId_columnName"] a').live('click', function() { 
    alert('hello'); 
});
```

The aria-describedby property should be in the format gridId_columnName, where gridId is the id of the element that hosts your grid: $('#gridId').jgGrid() ..., and columnName is the name of the column as defined in colModel, so in your case it would be "controlCenterCode"

The solution that I use is:

1. Use a custom formatter to render the link.
2. In my link, I assign a class (the class doesn't have to exist in any stylesheet).
3. I stuff any data I want to pass into the link as a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). data-id isn't stricty legal in HTML4, but it works in all the modern browsers.
4. Attach a live event handler to elements with that class.

Example:

```
// custom formatter:
return '<a href="#" class="actionButton" data-id="124">Click Me!</a>';

// attach live event
$('.actionButton').live('click', function() { 
    alert($(this).attr('data-id')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the afterInsertRow to get the Table Row (tr) element and attach events as needed.

$grd = id of Grid
.btn = class of element you want to attach click handler on.

```
    afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData) {

        var myTR = $('#grd tr:last-child');
        myTR.find('.btn').click(function () {

            alert('Element with class="btn" clicked!');

        });
    }
```